# Add Word "And" to Comma Separated String with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I have a simple string that lists items separated by commas. Before the last item, I would like to include the word "and".

**Example comma separated string:**

```
green apple, red strawberry, orange grapefruit, yellow banana
```

**I would like to display this instead:**

```
green apple, red strawberry, orange grapefruit, and yellow banana
```

Also, if there are only two items I would like to remove the comma (i.e. green apple and red strawberry).

Any ideas on how I can get started with this?

Thank you!

Comment: Hi. I answered your other question. At some point you have to learn what people are showing you and apply that learning to other situations. I showed you how to use an if statement inside a repeat loop to control how you work with the data. A simple if statement works here too. If you are on the last item then add "and" as you put your string together. Simple as that. You need to start applying what we are teaching you rather than continue to ask people for the answer. You have been given the tools to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use text item delimiters, count the number, and then handle each situation. This assumes no extraneous commas.

```
set s to "green apple, red strawberry, orange grapefruit, yellow banana"
set otid to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ","
set s to text items of s
set n to count of s
if n = 1 then
    set r to s as string
else if n = 2 then
    set r to item 1 of s & " and" & item 2 of s
else
    set item -1 of s to (" and" & item -1 of s)
    set r to s as string
end if
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to otid
return r
```